# IIS7 Windows Server 2008 Add Roles Stalls

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, compression

I'm trying to install Dynamic Content Compression on IIS 7 on Windows Server 2008 SP2.

Tried going to Server Management -> Roles -> Add Role -> Check Dynamic Content Compression.

Click next and it just says "Initializing installation ..." And it's been running for hours now. What should I do? I have installed Windows Updates, etc. And it still stalls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it takes around 2 hours to install Dynamic Content Compression role. I left it runs and it installed correctly. All happy now. :)

Comment: Glad you resolved this issue.  Please be sure to mark your answer "accepted" when you are able.

Answer (score 1):

Have you stopped the IIS service and any other IIS hosted services before running the role update?